# Possible to HTML scrape for LaTeX through a URL?

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, latex, processing

I've looked through many places for any LaTeX integration with processing (java), and can't find any that work. Although not all hope is lost as I have an idea.

Are there any websites that convert raw LaTeX to images, where I could access the raw LaTeX within the URL?

e.g;

https://www.latexgen.com/?text=2x+5-y (fake website).

where `2x+5-y` would be processed into a LaTeX picture.

From there, I might be able to scrape the HTML to find the image. Essentially creating a tedious, but functional text-to-LaTeX function.

I'm aware that a few modules aleady exist for Java. And that there are many websites that convert text to LaTeX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found exactly what I was looking for!

```
http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?\dpi{300} \huge x
```

Replace `x` with the LaTeX formula and the site will generate the image.

Comment: You should [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so the question is not marked as needing an answer.